# Possible bug in generic implementation of Default?

Tags: rust, traits

Given the following struct `Foo<T>` that derives `Default`:

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct Foo<T> {
    bar: Option<T>,
}
```

Why does this compile

```
fn create<T>() -> Foo<T> {
    Foo {
        bar: Option::default(),
    }
}
```

but this doesn't?

```
fn create_alt<T>() -> Foo<T> {
    Foo::default()
}
```

In my mind they are both doing the exact same thing--it shouldn't matter if `T` implements `Default` (which is what the compiler wants me to specify) because `Option<T>` implements `Default`.

[Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=14b323bc3c528f8285082f1bd07e64dd&version=stable) is a link to the Rust Playground with this example.

Comment: Note that this happens to several other automatically derivable traits, including `Debug`,  `Default`, `Clone`, and possibly more. The derived implementations require that all type parameters also implement them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue, and it's hard to fix. [Issue #26925](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26925)

In short, `#[derive]` uses incorrect bounds: it assumes that in order to implement `Default` for `Foo<T>`, `T` must be `Default`, when in reality `Option<T>: Default` is sufficient.

The problem with fixing it is that it's possible to have struct members of private types, and using `#[derive]` on a public generic struct that has private members could partially expose that private interface. For example,

```
trait MyTrait {}

struct MyType<T> {}

impl<T> Default for MyType<T> where T: MyTrait {}

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct PubType<T> {
    member: MyType<T>,
}
```

If `#[derive(Default)]` does the right thing, you effectively have this `impl` block for a public type that exposes a private trait:

```
impl Default for PubType<T>
    where T: MyTrait
{ ... }
```

Probably the best way to get around this right now is to avoid using `#[derive]` in this case and write the `impl` yourself.